# Vuetify component v-form is not responding on the declared @submit event handler

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify and VueJS (the latest versions).

Here is the small template of **Login.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <v-layout align-center justify-center>
    <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
      <v-card class="elevation-12">
        <v-toolbar dark color="success">
          <v-toolbar-title>Login form</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-form @submit.prevent="checkLogin">
            <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" id="userLogin" v-model="userLogin"
              placeholder="my@login.com"></v-text-field>
            <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" id="userPassword" v-model="userPassword" placeholder="password"
              type="password"></v-text-field>
          </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <!-- TODO fix the bug when form.submit not works -->
          <v-btn type="submit" color="success">Login</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

So, if you see, there is an *@submit.prevent* on *v-form* with *checkLogin* call and it is not working while clicking the submit buttor nor hitting the enter button while in input. Using *@submit* without *prevent* also has no effect.

But! If I put event handler on the *v-btn* like this:

```html
<v-btn @click.native="checkLogin">
```

after clicking the button (not hitting the enter in input fields) all works as expected.

So, can you please tell me, what am I doing wrong with the *v-form* submition event handling?
Thank you!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your submit button isn't inside the form so it's not triggering a *submit* event.

Either re-structure your markup or try setting an `id` on the form and use the [`form` attribute on the button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form), eg

```html
<v-form @submit.prevent="checkLogin" id="check-login-form">

<v-btn type="submit" color="success" form="check-login-form">Login</v-btn>
```

Note: The `form` attribute does not work for [any version of Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Btw, `type="submit"` is not actually needed, button `type` attribute has a `submit` value by default.

Comment: @mcmimik I always prefer to explicitly set the button `type`. It helps avoid any confusion or accidentally creating submit buttons when you want a plain one. Also, I was just copying OP's button code

Comment: Actually, `v-btn` must have its `type="submit"` specification to function as a submit button. By default type for `v-btn` is 'button'.