# Validate vuetify textfield only on submit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

> temp.vue

```
<v-form ref="entryForm" @submit.prevent="save">
  <v-text-field label="Amount" :rules="numberRule"r></v-text-field>
  <v-btn type="submit">Save</v-btn>
</v-form>

<script>
export default {

   data: () => ({
     numberRule: [
       v => !!v || 'Field is required',
       v => /^\d+$/.test(v) || 'Must be a number',
     ],
   }),

   methods: save () {
     if (this.$refs.entryForm.validate()){
       //other codes
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

[image]

What happens here is while typing in the text field itself the rule gets executed. I want to execute the rule only on submit. How to do that in vuetify text field?

Comment: What version of Vuetify do you use?

Comment: @Javas 
   "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.16"

Comment: IMHO validating only on submit would be bad usability. Is your goal to not display the errors while a user is still typing? In that case you could also delay rule execution until there were not input events for a few hundred milliseconds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vuetify `rules` are executed when the input gets value, 
But if you want that to happen only on the form submit, you have remodified the rules that are being bound to that input,

Initially, rules should be an empty array, when you click on the button you can dynamically add/remove the rules as you wanted, like this in codepen

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/subashdbc/pen/dybpPEj?editors=1010)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form ref="entryForm" @submit.prevent="submitHandler">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="6"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="user.number"
              :rules="numberRules"
              label="Number"
              required
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-btn type="submit" color="success">Submit</v-btn>
          </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    valid: false,
    firstname: '',
    user: {
      number: ''
    },
    numberRules: []
  }),
  watch: {
    'user.number' (val) {
      this.numberRules = []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitHandler () {
      this.numberRules = [
        v => !!v || 'Field is required',
        v => /^\d+$/.test(v) || 'Must be a number',
      ]
      let self = this
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (self.$refs.entryForm.validate()){
         //other codes
          alert('submitted')
        }  
      })

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: if submit triggered from `form` attribute. It doesn't work on first time. In your code you triggered from `v-btn`. Could u try the same code which i given

Comment: @vinieth check the updated answer, is this how you needed?

Comment: Now it works perfectly, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937829/vuetify-component-v-form-is-not-responding-on-the-declared-submit-event-handler?rq=1) the btn was outside the form. But for my case the btn is inside. Why was it not working. Any reason for it.

Comment: @vinieth if we remove `id`  from <v-form> and `from` from <v-btn> attributes also that did work. I just added `setTimeout` inorder to get reflected

Comment: @Subhash Why it is behaving like this(to take time to update the rules). Any reason for this.

Comment: @vinieth Not sure exactly.

Comment: Why do you need a setTimeout function?

Answer (score 16):

If you're like me and just want to prevent validation from running on every key stroke, apply `validate-on-blur` prop on your text fields and now validation will only be perform after user has completed typing the whole input.

So not an exact answer to the OP, but I think this is what most of us want to achieve. This prop has been documented [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props).

## Update 2024

Vuetify 3 introduces `validate-on` property that accepts several values including `blur`, so the correct syntax for Vuetify 3 users is `validate-on="blur"`. Thanks @epeleg.

Comment: Also useful when after submitting your form you reset all your fields, it will not trigger the rule of "required"

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: Underrated prop

Comment: this is now (vue3 jan. 2024)  validate-on="blur" as can be seen here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-validate-on

Answer (score -2):

I have another way to solve this problem without setting up watchers:

```
<v-form lazy-validation v-model="valid" ref="form">
  <v-text-field
   class="w-100"
   light
   label="Nome"
   v-model="form.nome"
   :rules="[rules.required]"
   rounded
   required
   outlined
   hide-details="auto"
  ></v-text-field>
  <v-btn
   rounded
   height="50"
   width="200"
   :disabled="!valid"
   :loading="isLoading"
   class="bg-btn-secondary-gradient text-h6 white--text"
   @click="submitContactForm()"
  >
   Enviar
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

There is a prop called lazy-validation on vuetify, as you can see on the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#functions

So, the v-form has a method that you can see through $refs called validate(), and it can return true or false, based on your form rules.

And, the function that will trigger the validation on submit will be like this:

```
submitContactForm() {
  const isValid = this.$refs.form.validate();
  if (isValid) {
    alert("Obrigado pelo contato, sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!");
    this.form = {
      nome: "",
      celular: "",
      email: "",
      mensagem: ""
    };
    this.$refs.form.resetValidation(); // Note that v-form also has another function called resetValidation(), so after we empty our fields, it won't show the validation errors again.
  }
},
```